# Mongodb client cannot connect to a remote db

Tags: mongodb

I'm running the following command to connect to a remote db:

```
mongo -u webui -p *** --verbose mighty5.***.univa.com:27017/univa
```

this command works on one computer, but my other computer fails. it seems that in my other computer this command tries to connect to a local db (and I don't have a local db in this computer).

even though I'm providing a password, the program ask me again for it

this is the output:

```
$ mongo -u webui -p *** --verbose mighty5.***.univa.com:27017/univa
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
Enter password: 
connecting to: abc
2015-12-23T13:48:41.525-0500 D NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
2015-12-23T13:48:41.525-0500 D COMMAND  [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2015-12-23T13:48:41.525-0500 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1)
2015-12-23T13:48:41.525-0500 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected connection!
2015-12-23T13:48:41.527-0500 D -        [thread1] User Assertion: 18:Authentication failed.
2015-12-23T13:48:41.527-0500 D -        [thread1] User Assertion: 18:Authentication failed.
2015-12-23T13:48:41.527-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1395:16
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

2015-12-23T13:48:41.527-0500 D -        [thread1] User Assertion: 12514:login failed
2015-12-23T13:48:41.527-0500 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 1509422 limit: 0
2015-12-23T13:48:41.528-0500 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 1222 limit: 0
2015-12-23T13:48:41.528-0500 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 3198 limit: 0
2015-12-23T13:48:41.529-0500 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 6 limit: 0
2015-12-23T13:48:41.529-0500 D -        [main] User Assertion: 12514:login failed
exception: login failed
```

I don't know how to debug this problem, any idea will be really appreciated

thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding --authenticationDatabase <name_of_the_database_where_you_created_user>

Comment: Hm ... are you sure you have the latest version of mongo process with which you connect to remote DB (I see that you remote DB version is latest 3.2). What happened to us one time is that we had latest version of DB (3.2) but mongo process version was from 2.6 and it refused to connect.

Comment: both (client and server) are 3.2. A coworker and I are having problem with mongoexport as well, we are having to different openssl errors, something about ssl v3. maybe those two problems are related to this one

Comment: did you get anything or not ??

Comment: We came to the conclusion it is a connection speed problem, from the computers with the problem ping time is higher than 95 ms